# Change pointer of variables

Tags: pointers, delphi

Given 2 variables (either boolean, integer, int64, TDateTime or string), how can I set A to always point to B?

Let's say A and B are integers, I set B to 10.

From here on I want A to always point to B, so if I do `A := 5` it will modify B instead.

I want to be able to do this at runtime.

Comment: Maybe you should specify you are using pascal.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the Delphi tag. Did that deserve a downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but the downvotes are probably because of the poorly formatted question.

Comment: `var A: Integer; B: Integer absolute A;`

Comment: @Branko how would I do that at runtime?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Although I agree with @Olivier, one obvious way to achieve the thing your Q is really asking about is to use pointers. `var
  a: Integer;
  b, c: PInteger;
begin
  a := 5;
  b := @a;
  c := @a;
  ShowMessage(b^.ToString);
  ShowMessage(c^.ToString);
  b^ := 10;
  ShowMessage(b^.ToString);
  ShowMessage(c^.ToString);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, and all of them are obvious if one understands what a variable is: a pointer to memory.

## Using pointers

```
var
  iNumber: Integer;   // Our commonly used variables 
  sText: String;
  bFlag: Boolean;

  pNumber: PInteger;  // Only pointers
  pText: PString;
  pFlag: PBoolean;
begin
  pNumber:= @iNumber;  // Set pointers to the same address of the variables
  pText:= @sText;
  pFlag:= @bFlag;

  // Change the memory that both variable and pointer link to. No matter if
  // you access it thru the variable or the pointer it will give you the
  // same content when accessing it thru the opposite way.
  pNumber^:= 1138;     // Same as   iNumber:= 1138;
  sText:= 'Content';   // Same as   pText^:= 'Content';
  pFlag^:= TRUE;       // Same as   bFlag:= TRUE;
```

## Using objects

```
type
  TMyVars= class( TObject )
    iNumber: Integer;
    sText: String;
    bFlag: Boolean;
  end;

var
  oFirst, oSecond: TMyVars;

begin
  oFirst:= TMyVars.Create();   // Instanciate object of class
  oSecond:= oFirst;            // Links to same object

  // An object is already "only" a pointer, hence it doesn't matter through
  // which variable you access a property, as it will give you always the
  // same content/memory.
  oFirst.iNumber:= 1138;       // Same as   oSecond.iNumber:= 1138;
  oSecond.sText:= 'Content';   // Same as   oFirst.sText:= 'Content';
  oFirst.bFlag:= TRUE;         // Same as   oSecond.bFlag:= TRUE;
```

## Using declarations

```
var
  iNumber: Integer;
  sText: String;
  bFlag: Boolean;

  iSameNumber: Integer absolute iNumber;
  iOtherText: String absolute sText;
  bSwitch: Boolean absolute bFlag;
begin
  // Pascal's keyword "absolute" makes the variable merely an alias of
  // another variable, so anything you do with one of both also happens
  // with the other side.
  iNumber:= 1138;            // Same as   iSameNumber:= 1138;
  sOtherText:= 'Content';    // Same as   sText:= 'Content';
  bFlag:= TRUE;              // Same as   bSwitch:= TRUE;
```

Most commonly pointers are used, but also have the most disadvantages (especially if you're not a disciplined programmer). Since you're using Delphi I recommend using your own classes to then operate on objects of them.

Comment: Is it not possible to change instead a "normal" variable to point to another, without using the pointer references? a,b: Integer instead of b: PInteger

Comment: Suggestive note: I don't like the hungarian notation, which makes your code - which is fine from the pascal point of view - more difficult to follow. Using `number` or `flag` makes better sense and is cleaner. Especially for class properties, it is awful to my eyes.

Comment: @hikari No, a pointer is an explicit type in the pascal language. `a,b: integer` are two variables. Only the `a: integer; b: integer absolute b;` trick may avoid using a pointer, but it may be tricky if both types don't match - e.g. if you write `b: string absolute a;`.

Comment: @hikari if it would be possible it would have been in my answer. Threre is no cheat available, no matter how often you ask and how much you wish for it - you still haven't fully understood what variables really are.