# Delphi "absolute" keyword

Tags: delphi

I read some articles like https://helloacm.com/absolute-keyword-in-delphi/ about the Delphi `absolute` keyword, but I wish to better understand how to use it.

Could you provide me a real world example about how to use that feature?

Comment: Have you read the [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables_(Delphi)#Absolute_Addresses) yet? The article you linked to has some good examples. So, what about `absolute` do you need more clarification on exactly?

Comment: Most ‘real world’ thing won’t need this. It’s more a low level performance issue, which depends on the situation.

Comment: `var A : TypeA absolute B;` means that variable `A` has the *same address* as variable `B` which can be helpful for low level optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately I cannot upvote your contributions because I have not yet the enough reputation.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: It's not mainly about optimization, but readability IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

When using `absolute` you can have another variable at the same memory address of a variable that already exists. Optimised excerpt from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63302470/4299358):

```
var
  Number: Integer;
  Text: String;
  Flag: Boolean;

  SameNumber: Integer  absolute Number;
  OtherText: String    absolute Text;
  Switch: Boolean      absolute Flag;
begin
  // Pascal's keyword "absolute" makes the variable merely an alias of
  // another variable, so anything you do with one of both also happens
  // with the other side.
  Number:= 1138;            // Same as   SameNumber:= 1138;
  OtherText:= 'Content';    // Same as   Text:= 'Content';
  Flag:= TRUE;              // Same as   Switch:= TRUE;
```

It also is a way to access a function's `result` variable when having cascading functions:

```
function FirstLevel: Boolean;
var
  FirstResult: Boolean absolute result;

  function SecondLevel: Boolean;
  begin
    result:= TRUE;  // This function
    FirstResult:= FALSE;  // The outer function
  end;

begin
  SecondLevel();
  // Now this function's result has been set already
end;
```

And it also can be used to wildly cast between types - it doesn't even have to make sense. But should:

```
var
  Letter: WideChar;  // 16 bit long
  CodePoint: Word absolute Letter;  // also 16 bit long
begin
  CodePoint:= $30c4;  // Katakana "Tu"
  // Letter automatically becomes 'ツ'

  Letter:= 'И';  // Cyrillic "I"
  // Codepoint automatically becomes $0418
```

Answer (score 3):

I often use it in this construct:

```
PROCEDURE LabelClick(Sender : TObject);
  VAR
    LBL : TLabel ABSOLUTE Sender;

  BEGIN
    .
    . // Use LBL.Caption etc. instead of casting Sender on every use
    . // or use an explicit assignment
    .
  END;
```

Answer (score 2):

They `absolute` keyword tells the compiler to create a variable at the same address as another variable.

In the example below, we declare a variable `Str` of type String[32] (Short string). This variable in memory is represented by a byte whose value is the length of the string and then an array of byte being the ascii code of the characters composing the string. The variable `StrLen` of type `Byte` is defined at the same address as the variable `Str`, the resulting effect is that the value of `StrLen` is the length of the `Str` string.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Str    : String[32];
    StrLen : Byte absolute Str;
begin
    Str := 'ABC';
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(StrLen));  // Will display "3"
end;
```

`absolute` keyword is somewhat an outdated feature. Using it is most of the time a bad idea. Use of a *cast* is probably better in almost all situations.

Comment: While this is absolute(ly) true, it is also one of the many caveats that we ran into when we became UNICODE-ified :-). As with most features, one should use it with care...