# Delphi - declare an instance of a variable in 2 different units

Tags: arrays, variables, delphi, reference, pascal

I've got a scenario where im trying to save on RAM by reusing variables.

There are 2 units where both require a fixed length array of bytes, so traditionally it was done by declaring such:

```
Unit A

var MyData: array[0..9] of byte;
```

AND

```
unit B

var Test: array[0..9] of byte;
```

There is no fear of data overlap as methods in each unit work separately from each other, but since they use the named variables within each unit (ie, **MyData** in unit A, **Test** in unit B), i was wondering if it was possible to let the variable "**Test**" reference the "**MyData**" without changing the variable name in the units.

Ie, all methods in unit A use the variable **MyData** and all methods in unit B keep using the variable **Test** as they do now but **Test** references **MyData**

So in effect i use only 10 bytes instead of 20.

What would be the best way to do this ?

Thanks bunches

Comment: My (12-year-old) computer has 16 GB of RAM, so I can fit 1073741824 such variables in it. How many do you need? You know that 10 bytes is absolutely nothing compared to the EXE size of your app?

Comment: Anyway: Static arrays are value types, but you could allocate the array dynamically and have two pointers point to the same data on the heap.

Comment: See also [Delphi “absolute” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67758188/4299358) and [Change pointer of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63302470/4299358)

Comment: Whilst your question can be answered, almost certainly the fact you are asking it indicates more important porblem

Comment: A possible other solution would be to export the variable in the global linker namespace. (like C callable functions) and reimport the variable back that way. There are examples in FPC to use variables from System without putting them in the interface, but I don't know if Delphi can do something like that.

Comment: *"What would be the best way to do this?"* The best way would be to change your code so that you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using the `absolute` key word.

In unit A:

```
Unit A

interface

var MyData: array[0..9] of byte;
```

and unit B:

```
unit B

interface

uses ..., A;

var Test: array[0..9] of byte absolute MyData;
```

In unit `A` you can use the `MyData` variable and in unit `B` the `Test` variable to refer to the same memory area.

On the other hand, there's not much point in it as you could just as well refer to `MyData` in unit `B` too (and completely skip `Test`).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that static arrays are value types, so the OP will likely copy the data over and over again as he or she refers to it. To guarantee that only a single copy exists, you should allocate the data on the heap.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'm not sure I understand in which case of my answer there would be any copying of data.

Comment: Not your answer, but the OP might declare `TTest = array[0..9] of Byte` and do things like `procedure p; var tmp: TTest; begin tmp := Test; ` which will copy the data. But maybe the OP will only ever read from the data.

Comment: @TomBrunberg First I wanted to ask if you could please use Pascal code (i.e. `unit UnitA;`) but then I saw OP's code.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thank you Tom, this is what i wanted.
Others : Thank you for  your inputs, i am aware of all the options but what i wanted (as above) is after careful consideration

Comment: @BitsInARow You are welcome! You do know, don't you, that you can mark an answer to your question as the correct one by clicking the tick mark beside the answer, green.

Comment: @TomBrunberg , thank you, now i know ! :-)